# GlassFish / Ubuntu Messaging

Tags: java, android, jms, messaging, ibm-mq

I was wondering ( i am not sure on the architecture i need here ) if it would be possible to have glassfish running on an ubuntu install on my desktop at home using jms, then using a combination of  a basic java application(using spring/jms) and basic android application have a messaging service running. for example the java application could publish the messages and the android device consume them? This might be a ridiculous question and I might be missing the point of how this all works but I wanted to try it out tomorrow if it is possible although id rather not try if it wont work!

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [*Using MQ Telemetry Transport Protocol in IBM Worklight Mobile applications*](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/312263).  This combination of MQTT in the device connected to WebSphere MQ allows seamless exchange of pub/sub between devices and JMS applications (or any other of the WMQ API platforms such as C, C#, Java, XMS, REXX, Perl, COBOL, etc.).

Some [benchmarking done on Android](http://stephendnicholas.com/archives/1217/) showed MQTT to be up to 93x higher throughput and 10x lower battery use than HTTPS.  That is probably why [Facebook Messenger uses it](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/building-facebook-messenger/10150259350998920).

To learn more about MQTT please visit [http://mqtt.org](https://mqtt.org/).  For an open-source MQTT broker, have a look at [http://mosquitto.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20210211165705/http://www.mosquitto.org/).  There are several publicly available and free MQTT brokers that you can point your client device at and you can test the JMS interoperability using a [trial of WebSphere MQ](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/mq).

Answer (score 0):

Never tried this myself, but you can certainly use a STOMP client like [Gozirra](http://www.germane-software.com/software/Java/Gozirra/) (the client binaries alone are just a dozen KB) and configure the message broker accordingly (I found [this guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2438/gjdkc.html), not sure it fits your current setup)

Answer (score 0):

You could install ActiveMQ on Ubuntu but it would be hard to get the client side working on Android, cause it is not supported.

An alternative is RabbitMQ which AMQP is a little bit better supported on Android.

I you really want to publish messages to Android devices I would suggest you take a look at Urban Airship. They have well supported platform for push notifications. Google GCM is another alternative for push notifications. Both are documented well.

Another approach would be using a REST/JSON interface between Ubuntu and the android device but of course, it does not support publishing.

Answer (score 0):

RSMB is 160KB trivially easy and free MQTT provider for Linux, Mac, Windows.  https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=d5bedadd-e46f-4c97-af89-22d65ffee070

And you can use Eclipse Paho's java client on glassfish and android.  Or download the Cordova phonegap plugin for Android if you want to create your mobile app in HTML5/javascript.